# where is the best place to start learning about servlet/tomcat?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I need to start developing using this technology servlets/jsp with tomcat. I need to get up to speed fairly quick. What would you recommend to get up there fairly quick?  No  900+ pages manuals. A good tutorial (even a video lectures) with lots of examples would be perfect.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Check out [simple.souther.us](http://simple.souther.us)
- Hanging out at [JavaRanch](http://www.coderanch.com/forums) is a good idea
- Getting a [Head First Servlet and JSP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516681) is worth it
- [J2EE tutorial](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/) is good to go too

Comment: Head First Servlets and JSP is more than 900+ pages, well +1 anyway for good links :)

Comment: Yeah, I was aware of that at the time of writing, and thats why I said having it is worth it. Thanks for the compliments.

Answer (score 3):

I would install Tomcat, and look at all of the included examples.  Each example shows a different feature or way of using Tomcat.  If you start tomcat up with the defaults, you should be able to go straight to http://localhost:8080/examples to view them.

Answer (score 2):

CoreServlets.com has a good tutorial using Tomcat 6.0:

http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/

or if you prefer a visual approach then check out this video (wchi additionally introduces Eclipse and WTP into the mix - but it's a good practice to use this to develop simple web applications):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-l0CFxdroTE

Answer (score 0):

I think that the following link will answer not almost all but literally all doubts that you have about servlets and give you a nice flow to study them.
this website is most appropriate since it provides examples as well and is more practical based teacher.
enjoy
http://www.roseindia.net/servlets/